# Can't run jupyter notebook with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Just trying to run jupyter notebook with pip. What the hell is happening? I tried to run it like this "python -m notebook", because just "jupyter notebook" or just "notebook" doesn't even get recognized.

```
C:\**\**>python -m notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\**\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py",
line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\**\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py",
line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\**\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\notebook\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "C:\**\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\jupyter_core\application.py", line 268, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "C:\**\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\traitlets\config\application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<C:\**\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packa
ges\decorator.py:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "C:\**\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\**\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1720, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "C:\**\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 1482, in init_webapp
    self.http_server.listen(port, self.ip)
  File "C:\**\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 152, in listen
    self.add_sockets(sockets)
  File "C:\**\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 165, in add_sockets
    self._handlers[sock.fileno()] = add_accept_handler(
  File "C:\**\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\tornado\netutil.py", line 279, in add_accept_handler
    io_loop.add_handler(sock, accept_handler, IOLoop.READ)
  File "C:\**\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packag
es\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 99, in add_handler
    self.asyncio_loop.add_reader(fd, self._handle_events, fd, IOLoop.READ)
  File "C:\**\**\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\eve
nts.py", line 501, in add_reader
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
```

Comment: Are you using virtual environments like anaconda? How did you install jupyter?

Comment: I've used it through Anaconda before, but I think i first installed jupyter solo with pip.. I've already uninstalled Anaconda with "Add and remove programs", do I have to do something else?

Comment: Jupyter seems to be installed, upgraded and OK.

Comment: You have multiple python versions installed. Uninstall them so that you only have anaconda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local installation of jupyter via pip is conflicting with your Anaconda installation. There are some situations where you may need more than one instance of python (e.g. if you need to test code with different versions of python, or some applications require a separate instance, but you seem like you might want to limit your installations to just a single instance.

Remember to use environments to keep your package list clean.

Comment: So it seems I really need to clean up. But I don't know how to. But thanks for the helpful answer!

Comment: If you feel like I've answered your original question it might be useful to others to select this as the accepted answer.